# Подключение к проекту локальной базы данных

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, visual-basic

Доброго времени суток всем!

Подскажите, кто знает. Проблемы с подключением к проекту локальной базы данных. Делаю

```
Add New Item, Local Database, имя, Add
```

Получаю ответ

> The data provider required to connect to local data file could not be found.
> The file will be added to the project but the typed DataSet
> associated with the file will not be generated.

Читал инструкцию – вроде всё верно делаю. Скачал и установил SQL Server Compact 3.5 – не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

В тексте ошибки сказано, что не найден нужный OLEDB-провайдер
Попробуйте вручную его зарегистрировать: regsvr32 sqlceoledb30.dll